# Neo4j simple Relationships not created with SDN/Spring Data

Tags: java, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have problems with creating relationships in a NEO4J Db with SDN.
The attached nodes are created, just the relationships are missing.

Aggregate Root Service

```
@Node("Service")
@Data(staticConstructor = "of")
public final class ServiceEntity {

  @Id
  private final Long id;
  private final String name;

  @Relationship(type = "handles", direction = INCOMING)
  private final AuthorityEntity authority;

  @Relationship("gives")
  private final ArtifactEntity output;

  @Relationship(value = "needs", direction = INCOMING)
  private final Collection<ArtifactEntity> input;
}
```

Artifact

```
@Node("Artifact")
@Data(staticConstructor = "of")
public class ArtifactEntity {

  @Id
  private final Long id;
  private final String name;
}
```

Authority

```
@Node("Authority")
@Data(staticConstructor = "of")
public class AuthorityEntity {

  @Id
  private final String name;
}
```

Neo4jRepository

```
public interface ServiceSpringRepository extends Neo4jRepository<ServiceEntity, Long> {

}
```

Whenever I save some Services it will create all the attached Service, Artifact and Authority nodes, but without any relationships. The view looks like as follows for `match(n) return n`

[image: Database state for example data]

For `match(n)-[r]->(m) return n,r,m` I get no records.

The Database Overview looks like this:

[image: Database Overview]

Comment: and maybe the most important&interesting part: how did you add the edges?;)

Comment: If you are using version 7.1.0 (which comes with Spring Boot 3.1.0), you might have been hit by this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/issues/2728

Comment: Thats probably it. Thank you very much. I'll try tomorrow and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Any @Node must have a valid @Id to have a relationship. Refactor your code like this:

```
@Node("Authority")
@Data(staticConstructor = "of")
public class AuthorityEntity {

  @Id
  @Generated
  private final String name;
}
```